# Value not Store in Dynamic SQL

Tags: t-sql

I've different different tables to categorically store data and a log table where all the transactions log are recorded 
e.g. 1) VoucherNO, Add, ... 
     2) VoucherNO, Delete, ..
After I backup the database and restore in another server for my Reporting Purpose. That time I want to ensure all the log data and transaction are available in TestDB if not then I remove log from 'AUD_USER_ACTIVITY'.

To find the transaction exist or not, I create a dynamic sql select statement and check whether record is exist or not. 
Basis on @RecExist Value I do the action like if records is not available in TestDB the log will be remove, if record exist immediately break this loop and going for next procedure

But @RecExist variable is not updating in Dynamic SQL Execution. Please guide me

```
declare @MvDocNo varchar(50)
DECLARE @SCtr as  DECIMAL(10,0)
declare @LocationCode varchar(4)
declare @UName  Nvarchar(40)
declare @toe varchar(30)
declare @QryTxt as nvarchar(MAX);
Declare @RecExist as INT =0;

SET @RecExist=0
WHILE @RecExist=0
      BEGIN
       select top 1 @MvDocNo=DOCNO, @SCtr=SrlNo,@LocationCode =DMLTYPE,@UName=TABLENAME 
           FROM R_AUDDB..AUD_USER_ACTIVITY 
           WHERE DBNAME='TestDB' and DMLTYPE not in ('AD','D','PD') ORDER BY SRLNO DESC;
           select top 1 @toe=docno from TestDB..M_TYPEOFENTRY  where TBLNAME=@UName;

       set @QryTxt='Select @RecExist=1  From R_TestDB..'+@UName+ ' Where '+@toe+'='''+@MvDocNo+''''

       exec (@QryTxt)

           IF @RecExist=0 
          BEGIN 
           DELETE R_AUDDB..AUD_USER_ACTIVITY WHERE SRLNO=@SCtr
              END
      END
```

Comment: The variable `@RecExist` doesn't exist in the scope in which `execute` runs the dynamic SQL. You can use [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with an `output` parameter to get the value. Note that parameterized queries are generally preferred to assembling bits and pieces as they avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: And using [`exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is a more suitable way to determine if a row exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code sample demonstrates how to check for a row in a table with a specific column and value using dynamic SQL. You ought to be able to change the values of the first three variables to reference a table and column in your database for testing.

Note that SQL injection is still possible: there is no validation of the table or column names.

```
-- Define the table to check and the target column name and value.
declare @TableName as SysName = 'Things';
declare @ColumnName as SysName = 'ThingName';
declare @TestValue as NVarChar(32) = 'Beth';

-- Create a SQL statement to check for a row in the target table with the specified column name and value.
declare @SQL as NVarChar(1024);
declare @Result as Bit;
-- Note that only object names are substituted into the statement at this point and   QuoteName()  is used to reduce problems.
set @SQL = N'select @iResult = case when exists ( select 42 from dbo.' + QuoteName( @TableName ) +
  N' where ' + QuoteName( @ColumnName ) + N' = @iTestValue ) then 1 else 0 end;'
select @SQL as SQL;

-- Execute the SQL statement.
-- Note that parameters are used for all values, i.e. the target value and return value.
execute sp_executesql @stmt = @SQL,
  @params = N'@iTestValue NVarChar(32), @iResult Bit output',
  @iTestValue = @TestValue, @iResult = @Result output

-- Display the result.
select @Result as Result;
```